# Do fairy chest stat boosts apply to all characters?

Tags: rogue-legacy

After finding all the runes, fairy chests instead give stat boosts. Are these boosts applied to only that character, or are they a permanent boost to the whole bloodline?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have tested this with a Hokage.  Prior to the Fairy Chest, he had 171 Strength.  With the permanent stat bonus of +1 Strength, that got bumped to 173 Strength.

I then fed successive generations to the castle until I could get another Hokage.  I checked their strength stat, and it was at 173.  So, yes, fairy chest stat boosts apply to all characters going forward.

Comment: "fed successive generations to the castle" is cracking me up. Also, yay for rigorous checking!